# How can i dynamically change the slider thumb icon image in a slider in javafx?

Tags: image, slider, javafx-2

have slider in fxml file :

> > Slider fx:id="slider" minHeight="20" minWidth="-Infinity" prefWidth="300.0"

Want an slider thumb icon image to be change from my .java class as I can change the thumb icon image by using `css`

```
.slider .thumb{
 -fx-background-image :url("your image");   
 ...// more customization       
}
```

But I want to change the image from .java class

Please suggest..

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can find thumb from Java code using [Node#lookup()](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#lookup%28java.lang.String%29) method.

```
String IMAGE = getClass().getResource("my-image.png").toExternalForm();

StackPane thumb = (StackPane)slider.lookup(".thumb");
thumb.getChildren().clear();
thumb.getChildren().add(new ImageView(IMAGE));
```

**N.B.:** Note you need to call this code after `stage.show()` to have lookup working correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but getting an null value in thumb 
StackPane thumb = (StackPane)slider.lookup(".thumb");
it thowrs an NullPointerException

where in .css file i have set 
.slider .thumb{
    -fx-background-image:url("../images/iconSlider.png") no-repeat;
   }